# How to test multiple inputs with chai.js assert?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a chai test for a function that loops through an object of inputs.  This code works properly.

```
they('should return the number of nodes in the graph', function (graph, expected) {
    expect(graph.numberOfNodes()).to.equal(expected)
  }, {
    basic: 6,
    withNewline: 6,
    doubleDigits: 13,
    nonConsecutive: 5
  })
```

But as an exercise, I'm trying to write it in "assert" style.

```
they('should return the number of nodes in the graph', function(graph, xxxx) {
    assert.equal((graph.numberOfNodes()), yyyy)
  })
```

If I leave xxxx blank and put in some number for yyyy, all the inputs get tested against that number.  But of course I'd like to test the proper output against the proper input, like the "expect" syntax does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  It was a simple syntactic mistake.  The correct format is this.

```
they('should return the number of nodes in the graph', function(graph, results) {
    assert.equal((graph.numberOfNodes()), results)
  }, {
    basic: 6,
    doubleDigits: 13,
    nonConsecutive: 5,
    withNewline: 6
  })
```